# PHP error after upgrading from php 5.3 to 5.6

Tags: php

I had this line of code which was working fine until I update the php version of my server from 5.3 to 5.6.

It re-writes a xml file.

I guess this line is not compactible with 5.6, but I don't know what is wrong exactly:

```
$newXml->asXml('my_xml.xml');
```

And this is the error message:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function asXml() on boolean in /usr/home/example/www/sites/all/modules/custom/inmovilla_rewrite/inmovilla_rewrite.module on line 71
```

What changes should I do here?

**UPDATE** Complete function

```
<?php


/**
 *  Implemetns hook_cron()
 */
function inmovilla_rewrite_cron() {

$xml_external_path = 'http://ap.apinmo.com/portal/mls/jamp623433/my_xml.xml';
$xml = file_get_contents($xml_external_path);


$pattern = '/<unico>(.*?)<\/unico>/';
$response = preg_replace_callback($pattern,function($match){
        $valueUnico = trim($match[1]);

        $valueUnico = substr($valueUnico, 0, -4);
            return '<unico>'.$valueUnico.'</unico>';
},$xml);



$searches = array();
$replacements = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 30; $i++) {
    $searches[] = 'foto'.$i.'>';
    $replacements[] = 'foto1>';
}
$response = str_replace( $searches, $replacements, $response ) ;


$newXml = $response;

$newXml = simplexml_load_string( $newXml );
$newXml->asXml('my_xml.xml');


}
```

Comment: I think `asXML()` is not supported in `PHP 5.6.x` anymore.

Comment: I forgot, I just edited my post to show the error.

Comment: We need more context around your code. As the error message already says you try to call the method on a boolean.

Comment: here something i got for you.. 
`$string = <<<XML
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

echo $xml->asXML();`

http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php

Comment: I posted the complete function to show the context.

Comment: @Rizier123  
I posted the complete function to show the context

Comment: It suggests that the simplexml_load_string function call has failed. Check the source xml you are reading from.

Comment: `asXml` is still a valid method. Your string manipulation is doing something wrong so therefore `$newXml = simplexml_load_string( $newXml );` is not creating a valid Object

Comment: I would bet this has always been a problem but the install of a new PHP has put `display_errors` ON and now you are seeing the errors that were there all the time

Comment: @SML Source is fine and public.

Comment: @RiggsFolly display_errors is OFF I just created a phpinfo() in my server to check it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly It was working fine until I change the php version. It was a valid Object working fine.

Comment: @canelones is what you assigned to $xml_external_path the actual URL?  if so there is a 404 error.

Comment: @canelones yea right of course it was

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the method: `asXml()` on a boolean data-type, not an instance of `SimpleXMLElement` - you are presumably not feeding in a "well-formed" XML string.

See here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php

> Returns an object of class SimpleXMLElement with properties containing the data held within the xml document, or FALSE on failure.

You should firstly implement some error checking rather than assume that you have a SimpleXMLElement instance, e.g.

```
$newXml = simplexml_load_string($newXml);

if ($newXml instanceof SimpleXMLElement) {
    $xml = $newXml->asXml('my_xml.xml');
}
```

However, you will need to do some further debugging on the values held in `$newXml` / `$response` to see what is wrong with the XML string. I cannot see the XML contents in your question to advise any further as to why the change of PHP version has affected this.